# Why is the accuracy of average="micro" the same as precision or recall in multi-class classification?

Tags: average, multiclass-classification, precision-recall

I have been studying multi-class classification metrics. In the process, I discovered that in the case of the parameter average='micro', accuracy, precision, recall, and the f-1 score are all the same. Through various investigations and examples, I was able to confirm that the values of precision, recall, and f-1 score are the same. However, I don't understand why accuracy is also the same.

In multi-class classification, I heard that TN is usually not considered, and only the TP of each class is taken into account. So, I think the formula goes like this. (The formula might be incorrect). I already know that denominators of precision/recall are consequently same. But when simply checking with the formulas, the denominators of accuracy can not be the same.

I'm sorry that I can't show the images directly :(

[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgNma.png)

I have brought an example from a [link](https://akash-borgalli.medium.com/confusion-matrix-for-n-x-n-matrix-488e8ff18321)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF3M1.png)

```
ttl_TP = 15 + 15 + 45 = 75
ttl_FP = 9 + 5 + 11 = 25
ttl_FN = 5 + 15 + 5 = 25.
ttl_samples = 100

micro-averaging precision = 75 / 75 + 25 = 75 / 100.
micro-averaging recall = 75 / 75 + 25 = 75 / 100.
micro-averaging accuracy = 75 / 75 + 25 +25 = 75 / 125. (not the same as above)
```

Some articles say that `\sum_{i=1}^{n} (TP_i + FP_i + FN_i) = \text{ttl_samples}` is equal to ttl_samples. This calculation would make sense, as it would make the micro-averaging accuracy = 75 / 100.

**I don't understand how `\sum_{i=1}^{n} (TP_i + FP_i + FN_i)` equals the ttl_samples. Additionally, I am curious to know if the formula I proposed is correct.**

I would be very grateful for any help.